# How can I disabled button when the button is already clicked depends on its row?

Tags: vue.js

I want to disabled button depends on the row that I clicked. The problem I received this error once I clicked a button.

> "Property or method "$event" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
>   either in the data option or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property, Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'target' of undefined".

Can somebody help me how can I disable a button depends on the row I clicked on my table?

```
           <tbody v-for="(medicine, index) in gulod_medicines">
                <tr v-if="index >= startIndex && index < endIndex">
                    <td>{{medicine.medicine_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{medicine.medicine_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{medicine.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{medicine.price}}</td>
                    <td>{{medicine.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{medicine.unit}}</td>
                    <td><button @click="gulodTransactionButton(medicine.medicine_id,medicine.medicine_name,medicine.price,medicine.description,medicine.unit)" v-on:disabled="disableButton(index, $event)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3" class="btn bg-success text-light" class="small-box-footer"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

           //methods
           disableButton : function(index, event) {
                 event.target.disabled = true;
           }
```

Comment: The error message tells you that `:disabled="disableButton(index, $event)"` is wrong. Doesn't it need to be `v-on:disabled="disableButton(index, $event)"`?

Comment: I try it the error disappeared but the button is not disabled. How can do it? I'm already new on vue I updated my codes above

Comment: when I try event.preventDefault() all the buttons are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is add a key/value to `medicine` -> `medicine.disabled` who would be a boolean set to `false` by default. And when you click on the button you set this `medicine.disabled` to `true`.

In this case I would do :

```
          <tbody v-for="(medicine, index) in gulod_medicines">
                <tr v-if="index >= startIndex && index < endIndex">
                    <td>{{medicine.medicine_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{medicine.medicine_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{medicine.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{medicine.price}}</td>
                    <td>{{medicine.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{medicine.unit}}</td>
                    <td><button @click="gulodTransactionButton(medicine.medicine_id,medicine.medicine_name,medicine.price,medicine.description,medicine.unit, index)" :disabled="medicine.disabled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3" class="btn bg-success text-light" class="small-box-footer"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

           //methods
           gulodTransactionButton : function (medicine_id, medicine_name, price, description, unit, index) {
                 this.gulod_medicines[index].disabled = true;
           }
```